# Is it possible to use two different ErrorDocuments for different paths of a website?

Tags: htaccess, apache2, 404

I currently run [PmWiki](http://www.pmwiki.org/) at mydomain.com/pmwiki. I have a 404 page and `.htaccess` set up in my site's document root for 404 pages regarding anything that doesn't have to do with my wiki. By default, PmWiki handles URLs a little confusingly so I had to use [this](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/Cookbook/CleanUrls) in order to get it to look like mydomain.com/pmwiki/Namespace/Page I had to create a `.htaccess` in /pmwiki to remove parts of the URL.

PmWiki also has a custom 404 (Site/PageNotFound) page that has stopped working, now my site uses the /404.htm page.

I noticed this when trying to install [this "recipe"](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/Cookbook/CaseCorrection) to enable case-insensitive URLs. Currently the only way to access Site/PageNotFound is by actually linking to it, and, if  you read how that recipe seems to function, this is an issue. Currently    mydomain.com/pmwiki/blahblah and mydomain.com/pmwiki/legitimate_namespace_but_lowercase/legitimate_lowercase_page_name both direct to mydomain.com/404.htm.

I have to admit I'm very confused, and I apologize if I was unclear in any of this, but I could definitely use some help.

Comment: Can you not set an `ErrorDocument` directive in your "/pmwiki/.htaccess" file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused with the explanation, but considering the title of the question ...

I haven't used PmWiki so I don't know it's details, but in any case, `.htaccess` overrides inwards, and by that I mean that any directive set in your root `.htaccess`, will be override by an internal `.htaccess`.

So if you want to have different error documents in some subfolders, you can do that adding a new `.htaccess` in those subfolders.

Bye